# Where are caffe libraries for sudo apt-get install caffe-cpu? Ubuntu 18.*

Tags: python-3.6, caffe, ubuntu-18.04

I have successfully installed the Caffe on Ubuntu 18.* using

```
`sudo apt-get install caffe-cpu`
```

The `which caffe` returns `/usr/bin/caffe`

I am successfully able to run `caffe` command on terminal, but problem is running the test files, as they are link to build directories of caffe and the problem is if I manually get the github repository of caffe and make build, it keeps failing and some of the dependencies candidates dont't have an installation candidate on Ubuntu 18.

Also all the examples on net available are for the previous type of manually built caffe

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it will use with the default python in /usr/bin/python3. You can check

```
/usr/bin/python3
>>> import caffe
```

With the python in /usr/bin/python3, it does not require to add any addtional PYTHONPATH